# Loop from start date to end date in Mac OS X shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, date

The date function on OS X (Snow Leopard) does not have the --date option like the GNU version and I am not able to figure out how to get the equivalent of the following on OS X:

```
startdate=2010-01-01
enddate=2010-01-31
foldate="$startdate"

until [ "$foldate" == "$enddate" ]
do
    # do something with the date here - like pass it as a parameter to a command
    foldate=`/bin/date --date "$foldate 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d`
done
```

SOLVED with answers from SiegeX:

```
startdate=2010-01-01
enddate=2010-01-31

sDateTs=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $startdate "+%s"`
eDateTs=`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $enddate "+%s"`
dateTs=$sDateTs
offset=86400

while [ "$dateTs" -le "$eDateTs" ]
do
  date=`date -j -f "%s" $dateTs "+%Y-%m-%d"`
  printf '%s\n' $date
  dateTs=$(($dateTs+$offset))
done
```

Comment: Glad to see that working for you.  I'm not sure what version of `bash` OSX has (if it even has bash), but if it does you should wrap your commands in `$()` instead of backticks like `sDateTs=$(date -j -f ...)` and use double brackets `[[` instead of a single `[` so you can do `while [[ "$dateTS" < "$eDateTs" ]]`

Comment: What is the purpose of the offset? Why is it needed?

Comment: Note that it's safer to use `=` than `==` in `[`, as use of `==` is an extension not all baseline-POSIX shells support, whereas `=` is defined by [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your date's manpage by running `man date` and look at the `-v` option. Here is an excerpt:

> **-v**      Adjust (i.e., take the
>   current date and display the result of
>   the adjustment; not actually set
>                the date) the second, minute, hour, month day, week day,
>   month or year according to val.  If
>                val is preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date is
>   adjusted forwards or backwards
>   according
>                to the remaining string, otherwise the relevant part of the
>   date is set.  The date can be
>                adjusted as many times as required using these flags.  Flags are
>   processed in the order given.

Comment: SiegeX, I did that, but cannot figure out how I would change anything other than the output of date with that option. In other words, I can add a day to "now" with date -j -v+1d, but how would I add a day to an arbitrary day?

Comment: The problem with -v is "take the current date ..." (from the manpage and above). I don't want to modify the current date, I need to modify an arbitrary date - one that I specify.

Comment: @hglattergotz looks like the only thing you can do is to save the current date to a variable then set the date to the $foldate and use `-v` to get the offset from that. Finally set the date back to it's original value

Comment: @hglattergotz actually, another option is to convert your offset values into *seconds* then convert your $foldate into epoch via `-j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $foldate "+%s"`. Add that epoch value to your offset in seconds and convert that back into a date via `-j -f "%s" $epoch_plus_seconds "+%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: @SeigeX, thanks for the last hint. Got it working now. Will post example as separate answer since I cannot seem to format it properly in a comment.